# How to use cppcheck's inline suppression filter option for C++ code?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, error-suppression, cppcheck

I would like to use Cppcheck for static code analysis of my C++ code. I learned that I can suppress some kind of warnings with `--inline-suppr` command. 
However, I can't find what "suppressed_error_id" I should put in the comment:

```
// cppcheck-suppress "suppressed_error_id"
```

Comment: It seems you cannot put quotes around the error id: e.g. it should be // cppcheck-suppress noExplicitConstructor

Comment: +1 for mentioning to call cppcheck with command line argument `--inline-suppr` to activate cppcheck-suppress. This should not be forgotten!

Comment: @SemjonMössinger Yes I was using the the Cppcheck GUI and it needs a checkbox enabled in the Preferences

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the cppcheck help:

> The error id is the id that you want
>   to suppress. The easiest way to get it
>   is to use the --xml command line flag.
>   Copy and paste the id string from the
>   xml output.

So run cppcheck against some code that contains the error with the `--xml` flag, and then look in the generated XML file to find its name.

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick answer, however the tip you gave works for --suppression option put in a separate file. I tried to achieve the same thing with comments just in my code, without luck so far with the use of these ids. Perhaps, the ids are OK and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @btz what makes you think cppcheck suports putting command line switches in code comments?

Comment: I run ./cppcheck --help and saw --inline-suppr option:

--inline-suppr       Enable inline suppressions. Use them by placing one or more comments in the form: // cppcheck-suppress memleak on the lines before the warning to suppress.

Tried to use it in my code (running cppcheck with --inline-suppr) with the ids taken form xml output, but it does not work for me.

Comment: @btz I hadn't notice that - just tested it, and you are right - it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, just tested it with the latest cppcheck version 1.44 and it works like a charm. Things you have to remember when using cppcheck-suppress:

1. put "//cppcheck-suppress <id>" in a new line before the line in which error to be suppressed occurrs.

2. provide the correct, full paths to cppcheck (I used wrong one with  /home/mycode/other_dir/../test.cpp)

3. Enjoy warning/problems free cppcheck reports :-)

Thanks a lot Neil.

Comment: BTW, I had problems with multi-line statements.  For example:
`// cppcheck-suppress errorname
cout << a   <newline>
     << b   <newline>
     << line with cppcheck problem;`

Would still result in the error, but this would not:
`// cppcheck-suppress errorname
cout << a << b << line with cppcheck problem;`

Answer (score 28):

You can change the output template to display the error id from the command line, which is quite neat.

For a Visual Studio format output with error id displayed, add this to your command line:

```
--template "{file}({line}): {severity} ({id}): {message}"
```

This will produce output something like this:

```
s:\src\jpeg.cpp(123): error (bufferAccessOutOfBounds): Buffer access out-of-bounds: abRY
```

Which you can then suppress by adding the line:

```
// cppcheck-suppress bufferAccessOutOfBounds
```

To the previous line in the source file.

Comment: You can use the same template to get a list of possible error id's: ```cppcheck --errorlist --template='{file}:{line},{severity},{id},{message}'```

Comment: Note that the "// cppcheck-suppress id" comment line should start from the first character of the line. It won't work if it is indented.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [cppcheck man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cppcheck), you can use the `--template` option to change the default output to include the id, e.g.

```
cppcheck /the/src/file --template='{file}:{line},{severity},{id},{message}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the GUI, you can right click on the message that you want to suppress to pop up a menu. Select "Copy message id". Paste the message id into your code in place of "suppressed_error_id".

Comment: Hi, can you describe in more detail what GUI you are referring to?

Comment: @Blaise, Sara is referring to the cppcheck GUI interface.