# Misleading performance warning for auto_ptr type passed by value

Tags: c++, auto-ptr, cppcheck

I'm checking one of my projects with *Cppcheck* 1.75, and for this code (reduced for clarity):

```
class TJob
{
public:
    TJob(std::auto_ptr<ITask> task);
    // ...
private:
    std::auto_ptr<ITask> m_task;
};

TJob::TJob(
    std::auto_ptr<ITask> task // <-- HERE the performance warning
    ): m_task(task)
{
    trace("TJob ctr");
}
```

I'm getting this new performance warning:

> Id: passedByValue
>
> Summary: Function parameter 'task' should be passed by reference.
>
> Message: Parameter 'task' is passed by value. It could be passed as a (const) reference which is usually faster and recommended in C++.

which is obviously a false positive. In my opinion it's a bug, because following this suggestion leads to a serious bug<sup>[1]</sup>, but maybe there is a switch that I missed to set, or some template I can provide to declare that **ownership is passed** by `auto_ptr`?

I searched the web for this and the only I found so far is that Cppcheck incorporates some checks for [*Check for invalid usage of STL*](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/ListOfChecks/#stl-usage), for example

```
- using auto pointer (auto_ptr)
```

I'm aware, that `auto_ptr` isn't the best choice but wouldn't it be the same with `unique_ptr`? Could it be that two checks interfere here?

Besides using [inline supression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2956331/2932052), is it possible to suppress warnings for those cases?

---

<sup>**Edit:** added the footnote.</sup>
<sup>[1]</sup> **There is no *serious bug***, only a misunderstanding about using `std::auto_ptr`. I somehow mixed up compile-time with run-time semantics: the ownership isn't passed by some compile-time magic, but rather at runtime by invoking the "copy" constructor.

Comment: What do you mean the suggestion leads to a serious bug? The ownership still will be passed to `m_task`, isn't it?

Comment: Really? Then I really have to take a deeper look into this...

Comment: If `task` is passed by value, then for `std::auto_ptr<ITask> my_task(sth); TJob tjob(my_task);`, the ownership will be passed from `my_task` to the argument `task`, then passed to member `m_task`; If `task` is passed by reference, the ownership will be passed to `m_task` directly. Isn't it?

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, indeed, I just built a littla project around it that makes this (partly) visible. I guess, that I read somewhere that `auto_ptr` (and its better successor) should be passed by value. How embarrassing that I blindly followed that ;) (I have to implement copy ctr tracing in my little test now, to see the whole truth...)

Comment: *`implement copy ctr tracing`* -- my bad, this is not possible, because this would require to go into the implementation of auto_ptr ;) So this must be traced in the debugger.

Comment: can you even pass auto_ptr by value? didn't it destroy the underline object too early / twice?

Comment: @Nick I think it's like [songyuanyao commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826329/misleading-performance-warning-for-auto-ptr-type-passed-by-value?noredirect=1#comment65019058_38826329), ownership is passed twice: first station parameter, last station member variable.

Answer (score 3):

It has correctly detected that you are passing by value to a copy constructor when you could pass by reference and amortise one of the copies. Your optimiser will almost certainly fix the 'issue' for you but there is not real need to rely on it.

I would say your expression of the interface is preferable in the auto_ptr's case because it tells the caller that you are taking the pointer, however I would say that the core issue is actually that auto_ptr is a bad citizen (can be left in an invalid state by a copy operation), which is why it was deprecated.

Comment: *`because it tells the caller that you are taking the pointer`* -- have you a reference at hand where this is suggested? I remember that I have read this somewhere... (Well, as I said, `auto_ptr` is bad.)

Comment: auto_ptr is functionally similar to unique_ptr, there  is only one owner. However it is from the days before move constructors and so the copy constructor is used to pass ownership, leaving the copied from object in an invalid state, this is why the const copy constructor has been 'deleted'.