# Cppcheck suppress unusedFunction for user library calls?

Tags: c, cppcheck, code-standards

I have a c library that I am passing through Cppcheck and am getting a lot of `unusedFunction` warnings for public calls that the user makes.

The Cppcheck wiki is quite unhelpful with their [checks documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/ListOfChecks/). Is there a way to suppress public unused function warnings and keep private (this static function only in this source is unused and warn). Or does anyone have an elegant way of tricking Cppcheck to not be bad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2956331/4688321

Comment: @kiner_shah yeah so you have to suppress each function in source, no such thing as private and public context to suppress globally

Comment: Not sure really, I just found a way and shared. Maybe you can try the [manual](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf), but I doubt there is something like that there.

Comment: I believe that cppcheck has public and private unused function for cpp clases, but it can't handle c context :(